# Istio breaks MySQL connection

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have an application that works just fine when deployed on regular K8s. I installed Istio on K8s along with my application. I configured a gateway and virtual service. Most thing appear to work except for internal connections to MySQL.

There are a few services that use MySQL and they can no longer connect to the database with Istio.

Any idea what broke? I am guessing it's something to do with the automatically injected sidecar proxy messing with the traffic. I am new to Istio and the docs are a bit scarce in places. Do I need to configure anything special for MySQL? Interestingly calls to MongoDB and Redis appear to be working. Confused :-(

Comment: Could you elaborate what exactly is wrong with MySQL connection? What kind of exceptions/errors you getting?

Comment: I have a PHP and a Java service that should connect to MySQL both of them are reporting that they are unable to connect. Connection refused, they just can not see the database. I have checked and MySQL is running and I can connect to it from a shell inside the container.

Comment: @SteveWW hey ! MySql doesn't work with my Istio (1.5) either... Did you found a fix ?

Comment: Looks like it's a bug with Istio, see answer below. At the moment I'm not using Istio with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple bugs in istio 1.0.3 preventing this. One is the / in the name, which the developers don't seem to think is a big deal, but breaks all stateful sets as they use a slash in the name. Once this is resolved, you can get a statefulset mysql up, but the connection is fubar, it connects but immediately gives a `MySQL has gone away`. The newer 1.1 versions appear just as bad. I think 1.0.2 has the last "working" version of Istio, but there were still major issues that made me try newer versions.

You can find the istio.yaml change here: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/9982